# What is probability that the component selected was produced by machine $III$?

Tags: probability

In a production line there are three machines manufacturing a component at a rate $100$ items per hour. Machine $I$ is running well and $98\% $ of its output within specifications. Machine $II$ is also running in control with $95\%$ of its output within specifications. Machine $III$, however is in need of adjustment, and only $50\%$ of its output is within specifications. An equal number of component from a production run of all $3$ machines is placed in a single bin, and a component is selected and found to be within specifications. What is probability that the component selected was produced by machine $III$?

I solved this but not sure. I didn't use more calculation here what I tried

$P(A)$ is the probability of selected component is within specifications,
$P(A) = \frac{243}{300}$

$P(B)$ is the probability of selected component is within specifications and produced by machine $III$, $P(B)=\frac{50}{300}$
then  the probability of component selected was produced by machine $III$ is
$\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}=\frac{50}{243}$

tell me is it correct or not if it is not please explain how to solve this!
Thank you,

Comment: It's hard to say if you're right or wrong (or what you might have done wrong) without seeing how you got the answer you got. Is there, perhaps, a theorem that you might have used to get that answer?

Comment: I will edit this

Comment: Your answer is correct. But whether you did the right way is not known.

Comment: @MathLover now I edited please correct me.

Comment: @ConMan I edited now

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @Math lover thank you